# Selecting the last record and comparing a datetime

Tags: mysql

I'm building a discussion board and I want to get a list of unread topics.

A topic should be unread and selected if the created_at datetime for the last post in a topic is greater than the last time the currently logged in user viewed this topic.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e2e99/1
If you delete all of the user view inserts ALL of the topics should be listed.

I have three tables:

**topics**

- id
- user_id
- created_at

**topic_posts**

- id
- topic_id
- created_at

**topic_user_views**

- id
- topic_id
- created_at

My query so far (but it doesn't work):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT `topics`.`id`, `topics`.`name`
        FROM `topics`
        INNER JOIN `topic_user_views`
            ON `topic_user_views`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`id`
            INNER JOIN `topic_posts` 
                ON `topic_posts`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`id`
        WHERE `topic_posts`.`created_at` > `topic_user_views`.`created_at`
            AND `topic_user_views`.`user_id` = 1 
        ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

I don't know how to compare a topic's last post's created_at column post to the last time this user has viewed the topic.

Comment: are you just trying to view the unread ones or do you want all with a bit field reflecting read vs unread?

Comment: @attila just the unread topics, where the topic's last post was created AFTER you last viewed the topic.

Comment: @MichaelCalkins add your expected result set in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way of doing it. we will use exists to test if the topic was viewed before the last topic post was created. see the sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e2e99/11

```
select t.id as topic_id, t.name as topic_name
from topics t
where not exists(
  select tuv.topic_id, max(tuv.created_at) as last_view, max(tp.created_at) as last_post
  from topic_user_views tuv
  inner join topic_posts as tp
  on tuv.topic_id=tp.topic_id and tuv.created_at > tp.created_at

  group by topic_id
  having t.id=topic_id)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: If there are no user views, how would I return all the topics? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ed40/1

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with :

```
SELECT t1.topic_id, t3.account_user_id, t1.created_at last_post_date, t4.created_at as last_seen_date
FROM topic_posts t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT topic_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at
            FROM topic_posts
            GROUP BY topic_id) t2
USING (topic_id, created_at)
INNER JOIN topic_user_views t3
USING (topic_id)
INNER JOIN (SELECT topic_id, account_user_id, created_at
                 FROM topic_user_views
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT topic_id, account_user_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at
                             FROM topic_user_views
                             GROUP BY topic_id, account_user_id) _
                 USING (topic_id, created_at, account_user_id)) t4
ON t1.topic_id = t4.topic_id and t3.account_user_id = t4.account_user_id and t3.created_at = t4.created_at
WHERE t1.created_at > t4.created_at
AND t3.account_user_id = 1;
```

This idea is to join the date of the last posted message in a topic (t2) and the date of the last seen message in a topic by a user (t4), and then you just have to filter out the results you don't want.

If I'm not mistaken, in the SQLFiddle you provided, there are no topics that have not already been seen by users, so this returns nothing. I slightly modified it ([you can see it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66da2b/1)) and it seems to work as wanted.

To consider the topics never viewed by a user, I think the best solution is to use the `account` table with a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. Something similar to :

```
SELECT t1.topic_id, t3.account_user_id, t1.created_at last_post_date, t4.created_at as last_seen_date
FROM topic_posts t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT topic_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at
            FROM topic_posts
            GROUP BY topic_id) t2
USING (topic_id, created_at)
INNER JOIN topic_user_views t3
USING (topic_id)
INNER JOIN (SELECT topic_id, account_user_id, created_at
                 FROM topic_user_views
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT topic_id, account_user_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at
                             FROM topic_user_views
                             GROUP BY topic_id, account_user_id) _
                 USING (topic_id, created_at, account_user_id)) t4
ON t1.topic_id = t4.topic_id and t3.account_user_id = t4.account_user_id and t3.created_at = t4.created_at
RIGHT OUTER JOIN account
ON account.user_id = t3.account_user_id
WHERE t1.created_at > t4.created_at or t4.account_user_id IS NULL
AND t3.account_user_id = 1;
```

which I did not test.

Answer (score 1):

With this example, topics also will be selected if user have not seen anything yet:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `topics`.`id`,
  `topics`.`name`
FROM `topics`
  LEFT JOIN `topic_user_views` AS tuv
    ON `tuv`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`id`
WHERE (SELECT
         1
       FROM topic_posts AS tp
       WHERE tp.topic_id = `topics`.`id`
           AND (tp.created_at > tuv.created_at
                 OR tuv.created_at IS NULL)
       LIMIT 1)IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```